# ScrollController: Jump to entry on short List

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView of ExpansionTiles and want to scroll to the selected one when tapped. In order for that, i calculate the height of all tiles and `scrollTo()` it via the ScrollController.

For large lists, this logic works well, but if the list content doesn't overflow through the bottom (in other words: small list, the content doesn't reach the bottom of the screen), then i scroll but immediately get a "bounce back" animation, which stops at the old scroll position.

Maybe someone has had a similar problem? I'm not sure if the fact that my list items are ExpansionTiles is even relevant, i could imagine that this happens with any children.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem, that's how list works. If the lenght of the list doesn't overflow the parent container (the number of items is insufficient) then there is no reason why the list should scroll.